# xsim changes case in `solution-name`

Tags: xsim

Consider the following example code for `xsim` (in German):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{xsim}


\DeclareExerciseType{Aufgabe}{
exercise-env= aufgabe,
solution-env= loesung ,
exercise-name= Aufgabe,
solution-name= {zu Aufgabe},
exercise-template = default ,
solution-template = default
} 



\begin{document}

\section*{Aufgaben}

\begin{aufgabe}
Beweisen Sie den folgenden Satz \dots
\end{aufgabe}
\begin{loesung}
Der Beweis geht wie folgt: 
\end{loesung}

\section*{Lösungen}

\printsolutions[headings=false]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it changes the case for the `solution-name` from "zu Aufgabe" to "Zu aufgabe". Why is this the case and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `\renewcommand\XSIMmixedcase[1]{#1}` somewhere in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[blank]{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseType{Aufgabe}{
  exercise-env = aufgabe,
  solution-env = loesung ,
  exercise-name = Aufgabe,
  solution-name = {zu Aufgabe},
  exercise-template = default ,
  solution-template = default
} 

\renewcommand\XSIMmixedcase[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Aufgaben}

\begin{aufgabe}
Beweisen Sie den folgenden Satz \dots
\end{aufgabe}
\begin{loesung}
Der Beweis geht wie folgt: 
\end{loesung}

\section*{Lösungen}

\printsolutions[headings=false]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

BTW: if you don't need or want the predefined exercise type `exercise` you can load `xsim` with the `blank` option. Then the environments `exercise` and `solution` will not be defined by `xsim`. (Probably not really important, though…)